# Using ADSL Modem/WiFi Router to share existing network wirelessly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

At my uni we have a wired Ethernet connection in our dorms. However, I want to share this connection with my macbook using wifi (so I don't have to be constantly tethered).

I am looking at using my DSL G064T ADSL modem/WiFi router as a wifi repeater for the uni network. Is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

I understand that it would be possible using a normal Wifi router (seeing as it has an ethernet 'in' port where it would get the external connection from.), so is it just not possible using the router I have? If i need to buy another one, which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to share the Internet through your MacBook. ( AirPort )

*System Prefs > Sharing > Internet*

Then "Sharing Your Connection From"; should be "Built In Ethernet" : "To Computers Using"; should be "Airport".

However then go to Airport Options and configure those to your liking. I suggest putting a password on and even renaming the network b/c you are at work and they might not like it, so name it something like "internet" or "default" so they can't pin it on you right away.

Yes,I think you could [use](http://broadbandforum.in/bsnl-broadband/49670-configure-access-point-repeater-mode-adslmodem-router/) your ADSL Router as a wifi repeater also should read the guide that comes with your router first and check there's Repeater Mode or not.

If you are okay with above facts, no more router(repeater) will be required.

Comment: Yeah, I can't for the life of me get Internet Sharing on my Macbook to work. I think it just might be the odd setup of the network here though. I will try it with my home network.

Comment: Just tried using this now, and low and behold, it worked with my DSi! Wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

Even though your DSL modem / Wi-Fi router doesn't have an Ethernet **WAN** port, if it has one or more Ethernet **LAN** ports you can most likely use it the way you want. Just plug a LAN port into the campus network, and turn off the NAT and DHCP services on your Wi-Fi router. On most devices, that makes it a simple layer 2 bridge between wired and wireless Ethernet.

As someone who got into trouble regularly by extending my university's network in unauthorized ways, I should mention that it's probably a good idea to check the Acceptable Use Policy for your network before you do this, so you know what rules you are or aren't breaking.